# Editing a editor with text and after clicking Done button the editor covers the whole page in iOS xamarin app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have a text editor in iOS and with Done button so when i tap it after typing something for edit the editor covers the whole area of the app and unable to edit.

I want to fix the height of the editor so that will be able to edit and save it.

I have used custom renderer for this and tried setting the height and width but not working as expected

> my xaml code

```
<controls:XEditor x:Name="Editor"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
```

> my custom renderer

```
 public class XEditorRenderer:EditorRenderer
 {
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        Control.SelectAll(Self);
        //this.Control.InputAccessoryView = null;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Can you post your code, and perhaps we can help you with it?

Comment: Sure i am using a rendered like  public class MyEditorRenderer:EditorRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            Control.SelectAll(Self);
          
        }

Comment: please edit your question to provide some more code to demonstrate what you have tried. What is the page layout? Your renderer doesn't seem to do anything. Provide as much relevant information as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is and Editor issue so i have tweaked it to creating a custom renderer and fix it

Comment: I don't have the code with me now but i have fixed the size of the editor rendered and it worked for me.you can try the same by creating editorrenderer.

Comment: if you are using no special buttion then u can add this.Control.InputAccessoryView = null;

Comment: For me, the keyboard overlaps above the Editor, the view doesn't got that much upwards. My editor is already under grid view. Can you help out?

Comment: Are you using any special editor like numeric or somehing